# In triangle ABC , ∠A=120∘ and AD,BE and CF are angle bisector of ∠A,∠B,∠C respectively Find ∠FDE

Tags: geometry

In triangle ABC , $\angle A=120^\circ$ and AD,BE and CF are angle bisector of $\angle A$, $\angle B$, $\angle C$  respectively Find $\angle FDE$

First $\angle ACF= \angle FCB=x$ so $\angle ABE=\angle EBC=30^\circ-x$. If I is intersection of angle bisector

$\angle CIA=120^\circ-x$ and $\angle AIB=90-x$ so $\angle CIE=\angle BIF=30^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

The angle $FDE$ is a right angle.

Let $G$ be the intersection point of the angle bisectors.

As $\widehat{A}=120°$ it follows that $\widehat{B}+\widehat{C}=60°$ and so in triangle $BGC$ we have two angles $\dfrac{\widehat{B}}{2}+\dfrac{\widehat{C}}{2}=30°$ and the third angle $\widehat{BGC}=180°-30°=150°$.

Same value has the angle $\widehat{EGF}=150°$ so that in the quadrilateral $AFGE$ the opposite angles $\widehat{AEG}+\widehat{AFG}=360°-150°-120°=90°$

You have to go on by yourself

Hope this can help

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem but mine ask to prove that $\angle DFG=30^\circ$ could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Let $K$ placed on the line $AB$ such that $A$ placed between $B$ and $K$.

Thus, since $\measuredangle KAC=\measuredangle DAC=60^{\circ}$, we got that $DE$ is a bisector of $\angle ADC$.

By the same way we can get that $DF$ is a bisector of $\angle ADB$.

Id est, $\measuredangle FDE=90^{\circ}.$

Done!